# MySQL #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables about music: songs and images, songs stores the song id, name, year, artist, audio. Artist is an indexed field it is in the images to identify the artist image. The problem happens when i  want to insert a song in songs. appears this error:

```
INSERT INTO `songs` (`id`, `name`, `artist`, `year`, `audio`) VALUES ('0', 'x', 'x', '1000', 'x.mp3')
```

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`audio_player`.`songs`, CONSTRAINT `songs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`artist`) REFERENCES `images` (`artist`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

both tables are empty.

any idea?

Comment: The song requires an artist. You need an artist first. Or maybe you can set that column to NULL

Comment: Why does the `songs` table have a foreign key to the `images` table? The foreign key should reference the `artists` table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i came too late, but: the error it's because i had to insert into images before  of data of artist table